# Eloquent query doesn't use the where/first conditions. Why?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ma simple eloquent query doesn't use the where condition.

> Players::where('id_player',"=" ,3113)->first()->toSql();

Returns:

> "select * from `players`"

**My Controller**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Office;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Players;

class OfficeController extends Controller{
   public function playerLineup(Request $request){
      $e = Players::where('id_player',"=" ,3113)->first()->toSql(); 
      dd($e);
   }
}
```

**My Modal**:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Players extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idp';
}
```

Comment: try `dd(Players::where('id_player', 3113)->toSql());`  what is the output?

Comment: It's the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you run `->first()` the result is a fresh instance of the `Player` model. then `->toSql()` on a fresh model is like `Player::query()->toSql()`.

you need to call `->toSql()` before that:

```
Players::where('id_player',"=" ,3113)->toSql();
```

or

```
Players::where('id_player',"=" ,3113)->limit(1)->toSql();
```

Comment: Good answer, I was just typing the same thing. :)

Comment: Thanks it works: "select * from `players` where `id_player` = ?"

Answer (score 0):

/*try to do this*/

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Office;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Players;

use DB;

class OfficeController extends Controller{
   public function playerLineup(Request $request){
      $e = DB::table('Players')->where('id_player',"=" ,3113)->get()->first(); 
      dd($e);
   }
}
```